# can't get php const value to work in pdo initialization

Tags: php, mysql, class, pdo, constants

I am defining constants in a class

```
class config {
    const DB_PDO_Connect = "'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=XdbX','XuserX','XpwX'";
}
```

In another class I try to create a new PDO object

```
class user {
    function login() {
        $db = new PDO(config::DB_PDO_Connect);
```

After that line, `$db` is not an object so something is not working, but if I replace it with;

```
class user {
    function login() {
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=XdbX','XuserX','XpwX');
```

(copy and paste the string from the config class)
it works.

I can echo `config::DB_PDO_Connect` so it can read it, the PDO just doesn't like it.

Comment: username and password are separate arguments to the dsn; simply comma-separating them in one long string gives you a single, invalid argument

Comment: Also, Would it not be better to create a database model class that does your PDO operations and pass that model to the user class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've actually done there is this:

```
$db = new PDO("'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=XdbX','XuserX','XpwX'");
```

Note that you've only actually passed in one parameter (which is in an unexpected format) and the last two are missing.

Architectural decisions aside (because you should really have a DB class to manage DB connections, and it's better to keep your config in its own file) why not add those two params to your config class?

```
class config {
    const PDO_DB = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=XdbX';
    const PDO_USER = 'XuserX';
    const PDO_PASS = 'XpwX';
}
```

Then you can:

```
$db = new PDO(config::PDO_DB, config::PDO_USER, config::PDO_PASS);
```

Comment: also, thank you for recommending using a db class.  I have downloaded one and am going through the code to learn how it works but I wanted to try a manual connection first.